# IIS start page shown when using non-https

Tags: iis-7, https, windows-server-2008

Just setup a new VPS server and am migrating a few clients to it from my dedicated server. The new VPS server is Win Server 2008 with IIS7.

For some reason, when you go to http version using the ip, you get the IIS Start screen. When you go to https version with the ip, you get the website. Why would the https version work and not the http?

I have the following bindings set on the site:

(Type, Host Name, Port)

http www.domainname.com 80

http domainname.com 80

https blank 443

What do I need to check or what setting might be incorrect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had the domain name in the Host Name param for the site bindings. When I removed that, it now works. This happened because I was using the IP address direct. It was answered by Shane Madden on Server Fault.

You can find out more about his answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/520070/https-shows-website-correctly-http-shows-iis-start-page